# How do I change call recorder file destination?

Tags: settings, file-system, call-recording

By default my call recordings are saved on the internal phone memory, in the Sounds directory.

How can I change this, e.g. to the external SD card?

(Android 4.1.2, Omega ROM v49, inbuilt recording option)